# jQuery - what's jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

can somebody tell me what is jQuery plugin? I have used the jQuery library to build some small UI enhancements but i have no idea how to implement a plugin.
Any suggestions on how to get started?

TIA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the best resource you can read concerning jQuery plugin development is the Plugin Development Pattern by learningjquery.com:

http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern

Of course it can't hurt to have a look at the official [jQuery Plugin Development Guide](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) and its [equivalent from jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Developer_Guide).

And to give you a (very) little insight... plugin development is really easy if you aren't completely new to jQuery. Basically, it is as simple as

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function() {
  // Plugin Action goes here
};
```

Which then could be used in the known way:

```
$(someSelector).myPlugin();
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend starting here: http://jqueryui.com/docs/Developer_Guide
Or if you want a complete tutorial, try this page: http://bililite.com/blog/understanding-jquery-ui-widgets-a-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

This is a decent screencast tutorial from nettuts

http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/learn-how-to-create-a-jquery-plugin/. you can also do a simple search of google

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=ySu&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=jquery+plugin+tutorial&btnG=Search that

will turn up many more.

Several more links can be found on the jQuery tutorial page.